# Search and merge json files

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking for a solution to search in json files and merge json objects on a match. For example I have two json:

JSON 1

```
{
  "guests": [
  {
    "customerID": 1, 
    "FirstName": "Max",
    "LastName": "Miller",
    "Email": "max123@gmail.com",
    "CreditCard": [
      {
        "Expiration": "12/2020",
        "FirstDigits": 0000,
        "LastDigits": 0000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "customerID": 2, 
    "FirstName": "Luke",
    "LastName": "Fetcher",
    "Email": "lf123@gmail.com",
    "CreditCard": [
      {
        "Expiration": "04/2020",
        "FirstDigits": 1111,
        "LastDigits": 1111
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

JSON 2

```
{
   "buyer": [
   { 
     "FirstName": "Max",
     "LastName": "Miller",
     "Email": "max123@gmail.com",
     "address": "Max Miller, Test street 1, NY",
     "products": [
     {
       "productName": "Test",
       "productPrice": 120,
       "Size": 43
       "Color": "red"
     },
     {
       "productName": "Test 2",
       "productPrice": 80,
       "Size": 43
       "Color": "yellow"
     },
     ]
   },
   {
     "customerID": 2, 
     "FirstName": "Luke",
     "LastName": "Fetcher",
     "Email": "lf123@gmail.com",
     "address": "Luke Fetcher, 1st Road, San Fransisco"
   }]
 }
```

My question is: How can I search and compare JSON 1 and JSON 2 for example by email, as both have emails as properties and if they match, add missing values from JSON 2 into JSON 1. In this case JSON 2 offers a product list and an address, which are missing in JSON 1 and as the email matches, it should add the products to JSON 1 too. I believe it should be possible with JavaScript somehow, but I have no clue how to do it. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Pseudocode: convert `json string` to `object`, then compare both `object` based on your logic

Comment: Can either of the JSON contain the same e-mail more than once?

Comment: @Slai no the e-mail is only once per json file.

Comment: @TheUknown how do I do that?

Comment: Probably using JSON.parse together with Array.filter or Array.find.  All of those can be looked up on MDN.